# Trying to highlight specific fields in an already existing document in Adobe Acrobat Pro, getting ghost image when trying to print

Tags: print-design, background, adobe-acrobat

So, I have a document that I am trying to highlight fields on.  I have lined up the highlights, but when trying to print the "image" of the highlight onto a blank document, the original document (which was scanned in for reference/placement of the highlights) prints as a ghost image, but 2 inches left of the original text.  I guess my question is why would this be happening and how can I avoid this when printing my document highlights onto a new document?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have discovered the problem... It seems that the document itself (a form from a distributor we use) had ink which was coming off on the printer rollers. So, fortunately I am not going crazy. Unfortunately I now need to figure out a new way for us to print onto these forms.